# How to create JSON from a slash separated String?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have a slash separated string format.

For Example

```
  myDecision/data/buyerDecision/data/buy = food

  myDecision/data/sellerDecision/data/sell = food
```

I want to convert it into following json format

```json
"myDecision":{
    "data":{
        "buyerDesision":{
            "data":{"buy":"food"}
        },
        "sellerDesision":{
            "data":{"sell":"food"}
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a different solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: First step will be to convert the list of path to a tree/node. The the serialiazation will be strait forward. There are multilpe question about tree view and path . While it's an other context it can be directly applied here

Comment: Json is just the serialization of one object. So don't focus on the object part for not but on the object that can represent those path.

Comment: @touseefkhan4pk What have you tried so far and where did you stuck?

Comment: _Why_ do you have this slash separated string format? It's kind of an XPath but it isn't. Does it support arrays? Are the values (in `= value`) always to be interpreted as strings?

Comment: And will the list string always containt a common root? if not what will be the Json representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is by handcrafting `JObject`s and then merging them. (This is not the most performant solution because it will recreate certain levels of the hierarchy several times.)

This approach differs from [Benzara Tahar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4413986/benzara-tahar)'s proposed solution:

- Tahar: Uses string manipulation to construct a valid json and then uses `Json.Parse`
- Mine: Uses path traversal to construct `JObject` hierarchy.

### Core logic

The core logic can be implemented as this:

```
static JObject CreateHierarchy(Queue<string> pathLevels, JObject currentNode)
{
    if (pathLevels.Count == 0) return currentNode;

    var newNode = new JObject(new JProperty(pathLevels.Dequeue(), currentNode));
    return CreateHierarchy(pathLevels, newNode);
}
```

- This is a recursive function, which builds the hierarchy from the inner most item to the outer most.
- So, if we call this method with the following `pathLevels`: `data, buyerDecision, data, myDescision`
  then it will generate something like this:

```cs
new JObject(
    new JProperty("myDecision",
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("data",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("buyerDecision",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("data", currentNode)))))));
```

### Calling core logic

First, convert the input strings into a dictionary where

- the key is the path
- the value is the desired innermost value:

```cs
var dataSource = new List<string>
{
    "myDecision/data/buyerDecision/data/buy = food",
    "myDecision/data/sellerDecision/data/sell = food"
};

var mappings = dataSource.Select(data => data.Split('=', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0].Trim(), parts => parts[1].Trim());
```

- **NOTE**: This is fragile because it can throw `ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added` if multiple datasource entries want to set the same property.
- We can loop through the dictionary to construct `JObject`s from the entries

  - The key should be split by `/` and then reverse the collection
  - The innermost value and the innermost path can be used to construct the `currentNode`

```cs
var objectsWithHierarchy = new List<JObject>();
foreach (var (path, innerMostValue) in mappings.Select(kv => (kv.Key, kv.Value)))
{
    var entryLevels = path.Split('/').Reverse().ToArray();
    objectsWithHierarchy.Add(CreateHierarchy(new Queue<string>(entryLevels.Skip(1)),
        new JObject(new JProperty(entryLevels.First(), innerMostValue))));
}
```

### Merging the objects

Here we choose the first object from the `objectsWithHierarchy` to collection to be the base `JObject` on which we apply/merge the rest of the `JObject`s.

```cs
var baseObject = objectsWithHierarchy.First();
var mergeSettings = new JsonMergeSettings {MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union};
foreach (var currentObj in objectsWithHierarchy.Skip(1))
{
    baseObject.Merge(currentObj, mergeSettings);
}

Console.WriteLine(baseObject);
```

The output will be the following:

```json
{
  "myDecision": {
    "data": {
      "buyerDecision": {
        "data": {
          "buy": "food"
        }
      },
      "sellerDecision": {
        "data": {
          "sell": "food"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Closing Thoughts

- This code is really fragile because it was designed based on two sample data without actual requirements
- The data format is quite unique so we want use things like [JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm)
- The actual use case is also unknown so the solution itself might provide very poor performance

  - in case of very deep hierarchies
  - in case of very large data source

Comment: this is a more resilient solution than mine, I had it in mind (I pointed the recursive approach in my OP) but I didn't want to invest too much time especially that the user who asks the question didn't bother to update his question with what he actually tried and didn't work (+1).

Comment: @BenzaraTahar I've just read your original post and I did not notice that line. +1 goes for you as well.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that comes to mind is this:

```cs
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stringObjects = new string[]
        {
              "myDecision/data/buyerDecision/data/buy = food",
               "myDecision/data/sellerDecision/data/sell = food"
        };
        var objectList = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (var s in stringObjects)
        {
            objectList.Add(ParseStringObject(s));
        }
    }

    static JObject ParseStringObject(string s)
    {
        // TODO! normalize input string (trim white space)

        var openingBrackets = "{"; // top level braket
        var closingBrakets =  new string('}', s.Count(c => c == '/') + 1) ; // +1 for the top level braket
        var json = $"{openingBrackets}\"{s.Replace("/", "\": { \"").Replace("=", "\":\"")}\"{closingBrakets}";
        
        return JObject.Parse(json);
        // TODO! handle exceptions 

    }
```

You need to install `Newtonsoft.Json` for this to work.

Other recursive approach might be possible though.

**Update**:
To have all the strings converted to a single Object, you can use the `Merge` method supported by `JObject`

```cs
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stringObjects = new string[]
        {
              "myDecision/data/buyerDecision/data/buy = food",
               "myDecision/data/sellerDecision/data/sell = food"
        };
        var resultingObject = new JObject();
        var mergeSettings = new JsonMergeSettings
        {
            MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
        };
        foreach (var s in stringObjects)
        {
            var obj = ParseStringObject(s);
            resultingObject.Merge(obj,mergeSettings);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resultingObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    }

    static JObject ParseStringObject(string s)
    {
        try
        {
           //remove whitespace
            s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", "");
            var openingBrackets = "{"; // top level braket
            var closingBrakets = new string('}', s.Count(c => c == '/') + 1); // +1 for the top level braket
            var json = $"{openingBrackets}\"{s.Replace("/", "\": { \"").Replace("=", "\":\"")}\"{closingBrakets}";

            return JObject.Parse(json);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // return an empty object
            return new JObject();
        }
    }
```

this should output :

[image]

Comment: OP wants one object out of those two strings.

Comment: You have the JObject and you can deserialize it to any class object you want

Comment: The issue is that the final property is not fixed. "buy" "sell"

Comment: That's not an issue. The issue is that your code returns two objects, not one as OP shows in their desired output.

Comment: yep you are right, I quickly misread the question, though he wants an array of object. I'll update the answer